# How to select in combobox value according to a table

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am trying to retrieve data from database and populate a form. In this form there are some combobox. This form is also used to insert data into database.Below there is a tableview. I select a row and clik on buttion and then data will be populate in the form. My question is **how to select only in the combobox the id matching data from database**. combobox is already populated by this method:

```
public void comboboxfonctiondata() {
    comboboxfonctionlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //handler = new DBHandler();
    connection = handler.getConnection();
    try {
        rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT num_fonction,nom_fonction FROM fonction");
        while (rs.next()) {
            comboboxfonctionlist.addAll(new comboboxFonction(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2)));
        }
        combofonction.setItems(comboboxfonctionlist);
        combofonction.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> {
            if (newval != null) {
                newval.getNum_fonction();
            }
        });
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `WHERE ....`???

Comment: If you mean the tableview which I said below I am talking about the form

Comment: You want to select specific row(s) from the db. You use a `WHERE` clause to do this!

Comment: For the textfield, I fill it with rs.getString. But it seems not easy for combobox.

Comment: With the picture I posted now I think it should be more clear for you.

Comment: I think that what Fabian is trying to point you is that you need the same query used to populate the combo but adding a WHERE clause to limit its results. The code to retrieve data and to repopulate the combo is similar to the one that you already have. You just have to include the new code in your property value listener.

Comment: Really I am confused. Let me explain again well because I think I am doing bad. There are 2 tables. A and B. A contains a foreign key from B which is the combobox. At the initialization combobox is populated from table B. So it is easy to add a new row. but the problem is when I am editing this row. Combobox should be populated and be selected first the foreign key. How could I say(foreign key = among combobox value)??? Sorry again it is not clear for me.